# Plot Gradients of Individual Layers in Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, google-cloud-ml

I have a GCMLE experiment and I want to plot the global norm of layer wise gradients in tensorflow.  I can ploy the global norm of all gradients in tensorflow, but I'd like to specifically plot the gradients for only the embeddings. Here is my current code

```
gradients, variables = zip(*train_op.compute_gradients(loss))
tf.summary.scalar("gradients", tf.global_norm(gradients))
```

I also know that I should be able to get all of the variables using `tf.trainable_variables()` but I am not sure what is the easiest way to separate out each layer? I'm guessing that I need to know each layer/variable name and create tensors representing the specific variables of interest? I think it would need to be something like:

```
list_of_embedding_variables = [somehow grab the relevant names from tf.trainable_variables]
embedding_gradients = [g for g,v in zip(gradients, variables) if variables in list_of_embedding_variables]
tf.summary.scalar("embedding_gradients", tf.global_norm(gradients))
```

Because I am running this as a GCMLE experiment, I don't have access to sess.run()/print all of the variable names. Is there any way to view the list of tf.trainable_variables() in the saved graph from a GCMLE experiment? Or to display these variable names within tensorboard?

**Option 1**

One thought that I have had is that I should create collections of the variables of interest -- for example if my embedding sequence is:

```
embedding_sequence = tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence(sequence, 
        vocab_size=n_tokens, embed_dim=word_embedding_size)
tf.add_to_collection("embedding_collection", embedding_sequence)

tf.summary.scalar("embedding_gradients",tf.global_norm(tf.get_collection("embedding_collection")
```

Comment: Are you using a "canned estimator" (like DNNClassifier) or a custom estimator (where you define your own model_fn?

Comment: custom estimator where I define my own model_fn -- added "option 1" as one thing that I was thinking may work, but it would require me to add each layer of interest to collections that I can then use to plot the relevant layers without needing to worry about the underlying variable names

Comment: @rhaertel80 I am thinking that I could also use variable_scope's and then tf.get_variable() with the scope regex to specify the ,ayers of interest and then graph the relevant statistics. Does this seem in line with what you would suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
        grads_and_vars=train_op.compute_gradients(loss)
        for g, v in grads_and_vars:
            if g is not None:
                #print(format(v.name))
                grad_hist_summary = tf.summary.histogram("{}/grad_histogram".format(v.name), g)
                sparsity_summary = tf.summary.scalar("{}/grad/sparsity".format(v.name), tf.nn.zero_fraction(g))
                train_summary.append(grad_hist_summary)
                train_summary.append(sparsity_summary)
         tf.summary.merge(train_summary)
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: will give this a try -- what is train_summary initialized as in this case?

Comment: train_summary = [] just an array which takes all my summaries (accuracies, losses etc)

Comment: what is the benefit of storing all of these in an array as opposed to just tf.summary.histogram directly which will still plot everything? This is largely working, but still curious how you are using the train_summary array later? The only change that needs to be added to meet my questions criteria is that you need to grab specific groups of variables which I am trying to implement with `tf.variable_scope`

Comment: You can merge one by one or mane an array and merge everything altogether. Depends on what you want. Also for the values from the `tf.variable_scope`, you can find it in the `g` (from `grad_vars`)

Comment: if `g is None` is this identical to a gradient of 0? or is `None` caused by something else?

Comment: if there is value (initialized) for `g`, just a sanity check. `g` will contains the gradients